# Reusing header/footer in tailwind UI for a static html site

Tags: html, tailwind-css, netlify, tailwind-ui

I'm creating a stupidly simple static html/css website using tailwind UI, and following this tutorial: https://justinjackson.ca/tailwind-ui-netlify

Whats the best practice for headers/footers so I don't need to manually copy/paste the html for the navigation over to every page and then recopy/paste any time I update the nav? I don't need full blown react or even a CMS, this is as vanilla and static of a site as they come.

Was thinking even a simple build tool that could add in the html for me upon build would work, but can't find anything. Open to other options.

Comment: Welcome to SO, this question will most likely get closed since it could be construed as seeking software recommendations. But I'd recommend you try out [Astro](https://docs.astro.build/), it allows you to make components from just HTML and does not compile with anything extra if Javascript is not used, also [setting up Tailwind](https://docs.astro.build/guides/styling/#-tailwind) with Astro is dead simple.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.